# Configure DBAL via Symfony2 to set charset

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, doctrine-orm, symfony

Does anybody know a way of configuring DBAL/Doctrine2 in a Symfony2 (symfony-reloaded) yml config file to execute a "set names" query? This question has been asked in other places, but I could not find a correct answer.

http://fossplanet.com/f6/%5Bsymfony-users%5D-symfony2-sandbox-database-collation-49626/

If there is no such config option, how can I implement this using PHP? Or better: Where is the right place in a Symfony2 project to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible yet. I am working on allowing this already, will be possible soonish.

Comment: Thanks for the response! In the example I linked above, the author is doing this kind of configuration somewhere else, could you image what would be a good place for this? I think there has to be some way of doing utf8 with symfony2/doctrine2/mysql!?

Comment: ok, a patch for this was applied to Symfony some days ago, the syntax would be:

    doctrine.dbal:
      connections:
        default:
           charset: UTF-8

Comment: I am not using Symfony, where do I have to set the encoding then? Currently I am using `\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"` in PDO's attributes, but it doesn't look like the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just for anybody else who might run into this problem. This is what I did:

I ended up subclassing `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` and introduced the method `getEntityManager`:

```
public function getEntityManager()
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    static $utf8_set = false;
    if (!$utf8_set) {
        $em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new MysqlSessionInit('utf8','utf8_unicode_ci'));
        $utf8_set = true;
    }
    return $em;
}
```

So everytime I am want to access the `EntityManager` or a repository in my controllers (which of course now subclass `DoctrineController`) I call

```
$this->getEntityManager()
```

resp.

```
$this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('What\Ever\Entity\I\Am\Looking\For')
```

Comment: This'd be better in a `DoctrineControllerTrait`. :)